# WCF Publish Method Procedure

Tags: asp.net, wcf, webdeploy

I am working with .net WCF. I have made WCF application and made web based application in .net to use WCF service:

```
public class AdditionWCF : IAdditionWCF
{
    public void DoWork()
    {

    }

    public int AdditionResult(int a, int b)
    {
        int res = 0;
        res = a + b;
        return res;
    }
}
```

both are working properly in local host. Now I want to publish both this application.

When I try to publish it, it gives me error like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you publish your applicaiton via the Publish command.

There are in fact many Publish methods:
- Web Deploy
- Web Deploy Package
- FTP
- FileSystem

In your example, it seems you selected"Web Deploy".

Web Deploy is the recommended publish method because it can automate the widest range of deployment tasks. However, before choosing this method, make sure that the hosting provider or server that you are deploying to supports Web Deploy.

At first, make sure that the remote server is set up for the Web Deployment Agent Service (MSDepSvc, also known as Remote Agent service), and that you have administrative rights on the destination server. Read instructions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569030%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

You simply need to specify server name and application path.

[image]

At the end, maybe web deploy is not the good approach in your case.

Comment: ok thank you for reply . i am trying same. But why did u said that web deploy is not good approach for my case ?

Comment: first, i'm not sure komoline.com/httpdocs/dhc_WCF/ is a server name. second, i'm not sure too you have privileges to publish to komoline.com/httpdocs/dhc_WCF/.